# Unusable module names with generate statement in cocotb

Tags: python, vhdl, ghdl, cocotb

Im using cocotb v1.0 and ghdl 0.35-dev (llvm and gcc backend).

The top level contains a simple for generate statement:

```
gen_pe : for i in 1 to 4 generate
    ...
end generate gen_pe;
```

I tried to access the first generated module in my cocotb testbench with: "dut.gen_pe[1]". It produces the error:

```
10000.00ns WARNING  Failed to find a hdl at index 1 via any registered implementation
10000.00ns ERROR    Send raised exception: gen_pe contains no object at index 1
```

When looping through the dut, it discovers the following submodules from the generate statement:

```
10000.00ns INFO     Found something: (1)(GPI_MODULE)
10000.00ns INFO     Found something: (2)(GPI_MODULE)
10000.00ns INFO     Found something: (3)(GPI_MODULE)
10000.00ns INFO     Found something: (4)(GPI_MODULE)
```

Unfortunately it isnt possible to access them with "dut.(1)", because it isnt valid python syntax.

Next I tried to execute the test array testcase from cocotb/tests/test_cases/test_array with:

```
make -s SIM=ghdl TOPLEVEL_LANG=vhdl
```

Almost all the tests are failing:

```
*************************************************************************************************                   
** TEST                                      PASS/FAIL  SIM TIME(NS)  REAL TIME(S)  RATIO(NS/S) **                   
**************************************************************************************************                   
** test_array.test_direct_constant_indexing    FAIL         2001.00          0.00   1640180.24  **                   
** test_array.test_direct_signal_indexing      FAIL         2001.00          0.00   1048707.02  **                   
** test_array.test_discover_all                FAIL         1001.00          0.01    145412.61  **                   
** test_array.test_extended_identifiers        PASS         2001.00          0.00   5155283.97  **                   
** test_array.test_gen_loop                    FAIL         1001.00          0.00   1166573.58  **                   
** test_array.test_read_write                  FAIL         1000.00          0.00    860546.57  **                   
**************************************************************************************************
9005.00ns INFO     cocotb.regression                         regression.py:358  in _log_sim_summary
*************************************************************************************
**                                 ERRORS : 5                                      **
*************************************************************************************
**                               SIM TIME : 9005.00 NS                             **
**                              REAL TIME : 0.05 S                                 **
**                        SIM / REAL TIME : 173326.30 NS/S                         **
```

Output of test_gen_loop is:

```
7004.00ns INFO     cocotb.regression                         regression.py:287  in execute                         Running test 5/6: test_gen_loop
7004.00ns INFO     ..tine.test_gen_loop.0x7fa35db6d4d0       decorators.py:191  in send                            Starting test: "test_gen_loop"                                                                                       
                                                                                                               Description: Test accessing Generate Loops                                                                           
8004.00ns WARNING  cocotb.gpi                                GpiCommon.cpp:353  in gpi_get_handle_by_index         Failed to find a hdl at index 20 via any registered implementation                                                   
8004.00ns ERROR    ..tine.test_gen_loop.0x7fa35db6d4d0           result.py:51   in raise_error                     Send raised exception: asc_gen contains no object at index 20                                                        
                                                                                                                 File "/home/Programme/cocotb/cocotb/decorators.py", line 197, in send                                              
                                                                                                                   return self._coro.send(value)                                                                                    
                                                                                                                 File "/home/Programme/cocotb/tests/test_cases/test_array/test_array.py", line 189, in test_gen_loop                
                                                                                                                   asc_gen_20  = dut.asc_gen[20]                                                                                    
                                                                                                                 File "/home/Programme/cocotb/cocotb/handle.py", line 342, in __getitem__                                           
                                                                                                                   raise IndexError("%s contains no object at index %d" % (self._name, index))                                      

8005.00ns ERROR    cocotb.regression                         regression.py:263  in handle_result                   Test Failed: test_gen_loop (result was TestError)
```

Thats similar to the error at my design. So I guess its an issue with the module naming.

Any idea how to get valid module names or fix the error completely?

**edit: Minimal example**

Folder: `/home/Programme/cocotb/examples/generate`

`/home/Programme/cocotb/examples/generate/hdl/top.vhd`:

```
library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity top is
    port ( 
        clk : in std_logic;
        A : in std_logic_vector(4 downto 1);
        B : out std_logic_vector(4 downto 1)
    );
end top;

architecture rtl of top is
begin
    gen_pe : for i in 1 to 4 generate
        test : process (clk) is
        begin
            if (rising_edge(clk)) then 
                B(i) <= A(i);
            end if;
        end process test;
    end generate gen_pe;
end rtl;
```

`/home/Programme/cocotb/examples/generate/tests/top_cocotb.py`:

```
import cocotb
from cocotb.clock import Clock
from cocotb.triggers import Timer

@cocotb.test()
def test_gen(dut):
    cocotb.fork(Clock(dut.clk, 1000).start())

    yield Timer(1000)

    for i in dut:       
        print i._log.info("Found something: %s" % i._fullname)
```

`/home/Programme/cocotb/examples/generate/tests/Makefile`:

```
CWD = $(shell pwd)
COCOTB = $(CWD)/../../..

TOPLEVEL_LANG = vhdl

VHDL_SOURCES = $(CWD)/../hdl/top.vhd

SIM = ghdl
CMD_BIN = ghdl

TOPLEVEL=top
MODULE=$(TOPLEVEL)_cocotb

include $(COCOTB)/makefiles/Makefile.inc
include $(COCOTB)/makefiles/Makefile.sim

sim: $(MODULE).py
```

After executing with `make`, the gpi-module names `(1) ... (4)` instead of `gen_pe(1) ... gen_pe(4)` are printed to the console.

**Update:**

The gpi-module names are fixed in the newest version of ghdl. However the cocotb test array testcases are still failing.

Comment: For a process labelled `inst` in the generate statement labelled `gen_pe` in an entity named `dut` with an architecture named `foo` the instance name would be of the form `:dut(foo):gen_pe(4):inst:` Demonstrated by a report statement reporting `inst'instance_name` in a report message, the ':'s  dictated by the standard. You're likely missing part of the path name, without a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's not apparent.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I added a minimal example and hope it clarifies my problem. I will try to take a closer look to the path names.

Comment: [Here's a tar archive](https://www.dropbox.com/s/elejswmurl4o0b0/vpi-ex-ghdl.tar.bz2?dl=1) of a C vpi program used with ghdl and your top.vhdl which returns the (in the VPI sense) modules.  The trailing colon (':') is an artifact of the PrintModule function. The Makefile has been updated for the latest release ghdl, and could require a bit of tinkering depending on your host.

Comment: I can reproduce the correct results with your C VPI program. So probably the explicit name of the generator gets lost somewhere in cocotb. I will try my luck to find it.

Comment: When you replace line 20 of `vpi2.c` with

    `vpi_printf ("Module %s:\n", vpi_get_str (vpiName, parent));`

do you still get the correct module name?

Comment: I saw you opened a ghdl issue on Github. No, with your change from vpiFullName (shown as a hierarchical name in the comments in vpi_user.h in IEEE Std 1364-2001) to vpiName (shown as object name)  it  just returns the generate statement iterated parameters in parentheses matching the issue you're having in cocotb.